# Difference between setf functions and functions

Tags: common-lisp

What is the difference between the following solutions (a setf function and a function)? Is one of them preferable, or are they only two ways to get the same result?

```
(defparameter *some-array* (make-array 10))

(defun (setf arr-index) (new-value index-string)
  (setf (aref *some-array* (parse-integer index-string)) new-value))

(defun arr-index-1 (index-string new-value )
  (setf (aref *some-array* (parse-integer index-string)) new-value)) 

CL-USER> *some-array*
#(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
CL-USER> (setf (arr-index "2") 7)
7
CL-USER> (arr-index-1 "3" 5)
5
CL-USER> *some-array*
#(0 0 7 5 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The setf function works as a *place* (aka. generalized reference). This means it can be used with modify macros such as `INCF` or `ROTATEF`. You do also have to write a corresponding getter function for them to work though.

```
(defparameter *some-array* (make-array 10))

(defun arr-index (index-string)
  (aref *some-array* (parse-integer index-string)))

(defun (setf arr-index) (new-value index-string)
  (setf (aref *some-array* (parse-integer index-string)) new-value))

CL-USER> (setf (arr-index "3") 10)
10
CL-USER> (incf (arr-index "3"))
11
CL-USER> (incf (arr-index "3"))
12
CL-USER> (rotatef (arr-index "3")
                  (arr-index "6"))
NIL
CL-USER> (incf (arr-index "3") 100)
100
CL-USER> *some-array*
#(0 0 0 100 0 0 12 0 0 0)
```

A setf function is generally preferred unless you are, for some reason, making a stylistic choice not to use setf or modify macros.